# How can I save images to my folder?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

When I try to save images to a directory, it's not saving to my folder.
Could anybody can give me some directions?

```
protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
{
  $formPost=$request->getParameter('planbook');
  if(!$planbook=Doctrine::getTable('Planbook')->find($formPost['id'])){
  $planbook= new Planbook();
}

$planbook->fromArray($formPost);
$this->form->getObject()->getPhoto();
$planbook->save();
//$this->redirect('@planbook_view='.$planbook->getid());
$form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
//if ($form->isValid())
//{
$planbook = $form->save();
$this->form->getValue('photo')->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_web_dir'));

//$this->redirect('planbook/edit?id='.$planbook->getId());
//$request->getFiles($this->form->getName());

}
```

Comment: Feel free to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and ask better questions - maybe then you will get better answers.

Comment: Thankyou Wladimir Palant...Thanks for your opinion... I will try to follow-up our instructions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->form->getValue('photo')->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_web_dir'));
```

Maybe you need to check this value `sfConfig::get('sf_upload_web_dir')`.
Directory exists, have permissions to write. Check the post value by `var_dump($_POST['photo']);`.